# Downloading all the files in a directory with cURL

Tags: bash, shell, curl, ftp, sftp

I am using cURL to try to download all files in a certain directory.

here's what my list of files looks like:

[image]

I have tried to do in bash script: `iiumlabs.[].csv.pgp` and `iiumlabs*` and I guess curl is not big on wildcards.

```
curl -u login:pass ftp.myftpsite.com/iiumlabs* -O
```

**question:** how do i download this directory of files using cURL?

Comment: Do you want to download *the whole* directory (and wildcard is not really relevant here) or just some files in it matching the wildcard?

Comment: @MichałGórny either one would be amazing!

Comment: do you have a simple solution :) ???

Comment: Are you bound to `curl`? To be honest, it's one of the most hard-to-use tools I've ever seen. What is your platform? Because in the post you mention bash, and in the answer comments you mentioned .bat files... Also, how is `sftp` relevant? And does your example actually use FTP? Because there's no `ftp://` there so I'm pretty sure curl used HTTP...

Comment: @MichałGórny no im not bound to curl. i need a tool that can access sFTP and FTP and download files. i am running on windows. i am at the same time looking for an app that will decrypt PGP after the files are downloaded

Comment: I'll answer you in a short while.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, considering that you are using Windows, the most simple way to do that is to use the standard `ftp` tool bundled with it. I base the following solution on Windows XP, hoping it'll work as well (or with minor modifications) on other versions.

First of all, you need to create a batch (script) file for the `ftp` program, containing instructions for it. Name it as you want, and put into it:

```
curl -u login:pass ftp.myftpsite.com/iiumlabs* -O

open ftp.myftpsite.com
login
pass
mget *
quit
```

The first line opens a connection to the ftp server at `ftp.myftpsite.com`. The two following lines specify the login, and the password which ftp will ask for (replace `login` and `pass` with just the login and password, without any keywords). Then, you use `mget *` to get all files. Instead of the `*`, you can use any wildcard. Finally, you use `quit` to close the `ftp` program without interactive prompt.

If you needed to enter some directory first, add a `cd` command before `mget`. It should be pretty straightforward.

Finally, write that file and run `ftp` like this:

```
ftp -i -s:yourscript
```

where `-i` disables interactivity (asking before downloading files), and `-s` specifies path to the script you created.

---

Sadly, file transfer over SSH is not natively supported in Windows. But for that case, you'd probably want to use [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) tools anyway. The one of particular interest for this case would be `pscp` which is practically the PuTTy counter-part of the openssh `scp` command.

The syntax is similar to `copy` command, and it supports wildcards:

```
pscp -batch login@mysshsite.com:iiumlabs* .
```

If you authenticate using a key file, you should pass it using `-i path-to-key-file`. If you use password, `-pw pass`. It can also reuse sessions saved using PuTTy, using the load `-load your-session-name` argument.

Comment: how did you do this so fast? did you know how to do this already or did you check documentation?

Comment: Well, I knew it should have something like this; I just needed a while to find how to get to the help of it, and how to make it working. It wasn't as easy as such things are on Linux...

Comment: does this handle sFTP? i have a key file that needs to be used in order to gain access to a certain ftp

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea. Also, do you mean sFTP as in ftp+ssl or file transfer over SSH?

Comment: Well, SSH on Windows is usually best achieved using [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). I'm pretty sure `pscp` work just fine (it's practically a `scp` counter-part). I'll add the simple way of using it to the answer.

Comment: Just for the sake of it (and someone might have use for the knowledge)
SFTP = ftp over ssh
FTPS = ftp+ssl

Comment: If you need to use key files you use the parameter -i [keyfile] . But in case you have a "normal" key you first have to convert it using PuttyGen.exe as described on https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/

Answer (score 68):

If you're not bound to curl, you might want to use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) in recursive mode but restricting it to one level of recursion,  try the following;

```
wget --no-verbose --no-parent --recursive --level=1 \
--no-directories --user=login --password=pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/
```

- `--no-parent` : Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.
- `--level=depth` : Specify recursion maximum depth level depth. The default maximum depth is five layers.
- `--no-directories` : Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.
- `--delete-after` : can be added if you need to delete files after downloading.
- `--no-host-directories` : to download right in '.' current folder, not create directory named by domain.
- `--no-clobber` : skip downloads that would download to existing files
- `--continue` : Continue getting a partially-downloaded file for more stability
- combine with `cd` : to define the destination directory

So this sample can look like following:

```
cd /home/destination/folder \
&& wget --no-verbose --no-parent --recursive --level=1 \
--no-directories --no-host-directories \
--no-clobber --continue \ 
--user=login --password=pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/
```

Comment: thank you very much!! do you know if it is possible to do the same with sFTP (ftp over ssh) ??

Comment: sftp is only an addition to ssh. When ssh is enabled you should be able to use scp as well and doing it with scp should be much easier:

scp user@ftp.myftpsite.com/mydirectory/\* .

You'll need to exchange SSH keys first to make that passwordless. And I'm not quite sure about the quoting syntax of * if you run this from windows.

Comment: The question is how to do this using curl, not wget.

Comment: In addition to that, the following parameters could be added for more stability: -nc, --no-clobber: skip downloads that would download to existing files and
also --continue

Comment: `--delete-after` can be added if you need to delete files after downloading.

Comment: `--no-host-directories` to download right in '.' current folder, not create directory named by domain.

Comment: For special characters in password, use quotas `--user="login" --password="pass"`

Answer (score 11):

What about something like this:

```
for /f %%f in ('curl -s -l -u user:pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/') do curl -O -u user:pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/%%f
```

Comment: I guess you were late to this question but this answer solved my problem for me so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You can use script like this for mac:

```
for f in $(curl -s -l -u user:pass ftp://your_ftp_server_ip/folder/) 
 do curl -O -u user:pass ftp://your_ftp_server_ip/folder/$f 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I have just the thing you need!

```
$host = "ftp://example.com/dir/";
$savePath = "downloadedFiles";
if($check = isFtpUp($host)){

    echo $ip." -is alive<br />";

    $check = trim($check);
    $files = explode("\n",$check);

    foreach($files as $n=>$file){
        $file = trim($file);
        if($file !== "." || $file !== ".."){
            if(!saveFtpFile($file, $host.$file, $savePath)){
                // downloading failed. possible reason: $file is a folder name.
                // echo "Error downloading file.<br />";
            }else{
                echo "File: ".$file." - saved!<br />";
            }
        }else{
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}else{
    echo $ip." - is down.<br />";
}
```

and functions `isFtpUp` and `saveFtpFile` are as follows:

```
function isFtpUp($host){
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "anonymous:your@email.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

return $result;

}

function saveFtpFile( $targetFile = null, $sourceFile = null, $savePath){

// function settings
set_time_limit(60);
$timeout = 60;
$ftpuser = "anonymous";
$ftppassword = "your@email.com";
$savePath = "downloadedFiles"; // should exist!
$curl = curl_init();
$file = @fopen ($savePath.'/'.$targetFile, 'w');

if(!$file){
    return false;
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $sourceFile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ftpuser.':'.$ftppassword);

// curl settings

// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

$result = curl_exec($curl);


if(!$result){
    return false;
}

curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);

return $result;
}
```

EDIT:

it's a php script.
save it as a .php file, put it on your webserver, change $ip to address(need not be ip) of ftp server you want to download files from, create a directory named downloadedFiles on the same directory as this file.

Comment: wow. looks amazing. can you please help me get started on how to run this? just put it in a txt file, rename to BAT and run ??

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. is it possible to run this without a webserver?

Comment: Umm, no! At the least, you'd have to install standalone php with cURL.

Comment: Ah, I personally use WAMP server. Check out [WampServer](http://wampserver.com/en/) and download any version and run the script or try XAMPP.

Comment: thanks so much. i am definitely going to try this solution, but in the mean time still looking for something i can run off my windows machine  in a BAT file

Comment: Couldn't you invent a more complex and heavier solution for a very simple problem?

Comment: Oh, I just pasted something I had already written. When I wrote this, I wanted it specifically in php, curl. So, at that time, it was the perfect solution for me.

Comment: can you help me something more ? if internet connection is interrupted during file downloading , then after i not want download file from scratch but i wanl resume.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did to download quickly with cURL (I'm not sure how many files it can download though) :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd where\to\download

set STR=
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%F in ('P:\curl -l -u user:password ftp://ftp.example.com/directory/anotherone/') do set STR=-O "ftp://ftp.example.com/directory/anotherone/%%F" !STR!
path\to\curl.exe -v -u user:password !STR!
```

Why **skip=2** ?
To get ride of `.` and `..`

Why **delims=** ?
To support names with spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to curl, you might want to use [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/features.html) , try the following:

```
lftp ftp://ftp.some.domain.com -u login@some.domain.com,'password' -e 'set ftp:ssl-allow no; mirror --Remove-source-files --verbose /remote/directory /home/destination/folder; bye'
```

Where

- `-u` username
- `,'password'` : put your password rather in quotas
- `--Remove-source-files` : deete remove files after you downloaded them
- `--verbose` : good to see info but feel free to delete on production
- `set ftp:ssl-allow no;` : only in case if you do not need to check certificate (not ssl)