# Using wildcards in wget or curl query

Tags: curl, download, wget

Is it possible to use wildcards in wget queries when downloading from directories? Basically, I have a site, say, `www.download.example.com/dir/version/package.rpm`. Howevery, the version directory changes all the time and sometimes contains multiple RPM packages. Is there a single wget query that would get me only and all the packages in the `version` directory without knowing what that version is? In my ideal world, the query would be something like:

```
wget www.download.example.com/dir/*/*.rpm
```

If there is a way to do this with `curl`, that would work as well.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in `wget` but the `-A` flag should work. From the [wget manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):

> You want to download all the gifs from a directory on an http server. You tried `wget http://www.server.com/dir/*.gif`, but that didn't work because http retrieval does not support globbing. In that case, use:
>    `wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.gif http://www.server.com/dir/`

Edit: found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783280/downloading-all-the-files-in-a-directory-with-curl)

**Regarding directories:**

There's a utility called [`LFTP`](http://lftp.yar.ru/), which has some support for globbing. Take a look at the [manpage](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html). There's another [question on Linux & Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17604/wget-recursive-for-only-files-that-pass-a-regexp) that covers its usage in a scenario similar to yours.

Comment: Ok, this allows me to specify that I only want the `.rpm` files. But, the issue of the ambiguous directory name remains. How do I tell `wget` that the directory name is irrelevant and to just jump to the dir that contains the RPM files.

Comment: @mart1n added info on lftp to answer, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 16):

If you are able to found a pattern in your query, you can use the bash brace expansion to do this task.

For example, in your case, you may use something like:

```
wget www.download.example.com/dir/{version,old}/package{00..99}.rpm
```

Also, you may combine this with the `-A` and `-R` parameters to filter your results.

Answer (score 3):

Although the above solution kind of works, it fails when you just want to download certain directories, but not all. For example if you have:

```
http://site.io/like/
http://site.io/like2/
http://site.io/nolike/
```

Instead put the directory names you want in a text file, e.g.: 
***dirs.txt:***

```
like/
like2/
```

Then use `wget` with the following command options `-i dirs.txt -B <base-URL>` like so:

```
wget -nH -nc -np -r -e robots=off -R "index.html*" -i dirs.txt -B http://site.io/
```

Since, I don't think you can use directories in the `-A` and `-R` lists. (?)