# Wildcard download using wget / curl

Tags: curl, download, wget

I tried to download all perl rpm file from centos repo. I tried it by using "wget" command. But its not working.

Pls someone help thanks.

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A 'perl-*.el7.x86_64.rpm' http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/
```

Comment: This is working fine over here. What precisely does happen on your end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using wildcards in wget or curl query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107236/using-wildcards-in-wget-or-curl-query)