# Download ftp directory content from 1000 genomes data

Tags: ftp, sequence, fastq, raw-data

I have to download a bunch of sequence files stored at 1000 genomes subdirectories, which are stored at a main directory called MXL:
ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data_collections/1000_genomes_project/data/MXL/

I tried to use the command $ curl ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data_collections/1000_genomes_project/data/MXL/

But it did not work. I also tried the following code:

1. ftp ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data_collections/1000_genomes_project/data/MXL/
2. wget -r ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data_collections/1000_genomes_project/data/MXL/*

None of the above worked.

I want to download all the files nested at MXL subdirectories at once. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [downloading all the files in a directory with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783280/downloading-all-the-files-in-a-directory-with-curl)

Comment: Thank you, although is not the same situation, because I have subdirectories, then the files into them.

Comment: Did you read all answers? There is one dealing with nested directories. Although this one uses `wget` instead of curl.