# Downloading files from sftp server with wildcard and in a loop

Tags: bash, get, sftp, wildcard

I am trying to download a bunch of files from a sftp server. The organization of the server is the following: there is a folder per year, and each yearly folder, there is a folder per day. In each day, there are 8 files ending in `.nc` that I want to download. The names of the files themselves are too crazy to keep track of. I have tried a few different approaches but I have not been successful in giving `get` the right instructions to get the files.
My current version is to have a loop before connecting to the sftp so I can write the name and then connect to the sftp and download that file:

```
for i in `seq 1 1 366`;
        do
            if [ $i -lt 10 ]; then
                today='00$i/*.nc' 
            elif [ $i -ge 10 ] && [ $i -lt 100 ]; then
                today= '0$i/*.nc' 
            elif [ $i -ge 100 ]; then
                today= '$i/*.nc' 
            fi
        done

sshpass -p $(cat ~/Code/sftp_passwd.txt) sftp cgerlein@cygnss-sftp-1.engin.umich.edu <<EOF

cd ..
cd ..
cd /data/cygnss/products/CDR/l1/2019/

get $today /scratch/myfolder/ 
quit
EOF
```

I don't think `get` is liking the wildcard in there. And this might not even be the best approach. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

Comment: BTW, you can use `$(printf '%03d' $i)` to get a number with leading zeroes, instead of the `if` statements.

Comment: I think you need to use the `mget` command to get multiple files with a wildcard.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, the double quotes + `mget` works but now it downloads all the files from the first folder and then it stops. I tried putting the `sshpass` [ ...] `quit EOF` inside teh `do` loop but that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I think it was just something weird with the tabulations, but it now seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: You can't indent the `EOF` token in a here-doc unless use use `<<-EOF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `printf()` to format the filename with leading zeroes.

The `sftp` command needs to be inside the loop.

You can't have a space after `today=`.

There's no need for `cd ..` before changing to an absolute pathname.

```
for i in {1..366}
do
    today=$(printf "%03d/*.nc" $i)
    sshpass -p $(cat ~/Code/sftp_passwd.txt) sftp cgerlein@cygnss-sftp-1.engin.umich.edu <<EOF
cd /data/cygnss/products/CDR/l1/2019/
get $today /scratch/myfolder/ 
quit
EOF
done
```

BTW, you can do wildcard downloads with `curl`, see [downloading all the files in a directory with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783280/downloading-all-the-files-in-a-directory-with-curl)

Comment: OK, then it was all the other problems.